# java: constructor cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

please help a noob. 
I am trying to run a project in which I have 2 classes, one test class and in the other one I have the constructor and methods.

I have to input the course's name and the instructor's name, 
-create 2 objects for each of them
-read from the keyboard both of them
-print the result

Full error message:

Error:(14, 29) java: constructor GradeBook in class GradeBook cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I have previously researched questions on this topic but I was unable to find one that helps me.

Here is the class with the constructor:

```
public class GradeBook{

    private String courseName; //course name for this gradebook
    private String instrName; //instructor's name for this gradebook

    //constructor initializes coursename with String argument
    public GradeBook(String name, String nameinstr)
    {
        courseName = name; //initializes courseName with name
         instrName = nameinstr; //initializez instrName with nameinstr

    }

    //method to set the instructor name;
    public void setInstrName(String nameinstr)
    {
        instrName = nameinstr;
    }

    public String getInstrName() //method to get the instructor name
    {
        return instrName;
    }
    //method to set the coursename

    public void setCourseName(String name)
    {
        courseName = name; //store the course name
    }

    //method to return the coursename

    public String getCourseName()
    {
        return courseName;
    }//end method getCourseName

    public void displayMessage()
    {
        System.out.printf("The course name is %s\n\n", getCourseName());
        System.out.printf("The name of the instructor is %s\n", getInstrName());
                //this statement calls getCoursename to get the name of the course this GradeBook represents
    }//end method displayMessage
}//end class GradeBook
```

And here is the class for testing it:

```
public class GradeBookTest

{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        GradeBook course1 = new GradeBook(); //object 1 for the course name
        GradeBook instructor1 = new GradeBook(); //object 2 for the instructor's name

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the course:\n");
        String theName = input.nextLine();
        course1.setCourseName( theName );
        System.out.println();


        System.out.println("Enter the name of the instructor: \n");
        String theName2 = input.nextLine();
        instructor1.setInstrName( theName2);
        System.out.println();




        course1.displayMessage();
        instructor1.displayMessage();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for the noob question

Comment: just as the error message states, you only defined one constroctor for `GradeBook`, as `GradeBook(String name, String nameinstr)`. But you are calling it without parameters, as `new GradeBook()`, so the error tells you to pass two `String's`, which would fit your constructor. Otherswise if you don´t want to pass the parameter, define another no parameter constructor in your class.

Comment: declare `default constructor` in class `GradeBook`

Comment: @KevinEsche  

I declared a default constructor in class GradeBook as public GradeBook(){}        Now, when I run the program I get the following output:   Enter the name of the course:

English

Enter the name of the instructor: 

Professor Oak

The course name is English

The name of the instructor is null
The course name is null

The name of the instructor is Professor Oak